# How to avoid EOF method in controller

Tags: php

I recently implement the CIC payment solution. everything is OK except the last process,
In order to validate the last step, I need to send an acknowledge to the bank in “plain/text” format

```
version=2
cdr=0
```

I’ve tried to put this content in a text file in order to get it with a simple file_get_content(). but it’s not working.

The only solution i found is :

```
$acknowledge = <<< EOF
version=2
cdr=0
EOF;
```

which is an ugly solution I think because it breaks the current identation. is there another solution ?

Comment: Let me guess... You've mistyped `file_get_contents()` but your PHP development box is configured to hide all helpful error messages?

Comment: What about using `$acknowledge = "version=2" . PHP_EOL . "cdr=0";`? The `PHP_EOL` constant would deal with the new line character on the actual server the code is executed on.

Comment: Thank you Tibor your solution is great !

Answer (score 0):

There're endless ways to print text in PHP. Among the simplests, we have [echo](http://php.net/echo):

```
echo "version=2\ncdr=0";
```